# How can I checkout to a remote branch locally when it is created after cloning

Tags: git

I cloned a git repo. Now there is a new branch in remote repo which is created after I cloned to my local. How can I fetch this new remote branch to my local repo?

Comment: Note that the phrase *remote branch* is either nonsense, or at least ambiguous. A *branch name* is local: e.g., `master` is short for `refs/heads/master`, which is your (local) `master`. A *remote-tracking name* like `origin/master` is short for `refs/remotes/origin/master`; that's not a *branch name*. A different Git repository, such as the one that you got your `origin/master` *from*, has the branch name `master`, not `origin/master`: that might be the best bet for assigning meaning to the term "remote branch", but that tends not to be what people actually mean when they say it.

Comment: I recommend avoiding the phrase "remote branch" entirely. To refer to a remote-tracking name like `origin/master`, just use the phrase *remote-tracking name*. (Git calls this a *remote-tracking branch name* but that just invites the ambiguous abbreviations, so I drop the word *branch* myself.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git fetch` to get the remote branch you are interested in.
For example, if you want to fetch a branch named `source` from the remote `origin`, and setup a local branch `dest` to track the remote branch, you can do:

```
git fetch -u origin source:dest
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that `git fetch` creates *remote-tracking names* from the other Git's branch names.  That is, if the remote named `origin` has a new branch named `feature/tall` that it did not have before, and you run:

```
git fetch origin
```

you will, afterward, have a new remote-tracking name, `origin/feature/tall`.

You can, if you like, check out the specific commit to which this remote-tracking name points:

```
git checkout origin/feature/tall
```

but this puts your own Git into what Git calls *detached HEAD* mode.  This is good for looking at a commit, or even building one, but it's rarely a good way to do any actual work and make new commits.

To make a new *branch name* in your own repository, there are two or three primary Git commands (three if you are on Git 2.23 or later):

- `git branch` is the general-purpose command for manipulating branch names, listing branch names, listing remote-tracking names, and the like.
- `git checkout` has the `-b` option to create a new (local) branch name.<sup>1</sup>
- `git switch` has the `-c` option to create a new branch name.

Remember that a branch name identifies one specific commit—Git calls this one specific commit the *tip commit* of that branch—and provides a few extra features, such as the ability to use `git checkout` or `git switch` to be *on* that branch.  Once you are on the branch—so that `git status` says `on branch branch`—each *new* commit will automatically be the tip commit of that branch, because Git will write the new commit's hash ID into the branch name at the time you make the new commit.

Hence, when you choose to create a new branch, you can do so using any existing commit's hash ID.  It's very common to want to create your own new branch `feature/tall` based on your existing `origin/feature/tall` remote-tracking name.  For this reason, both `git checkout` and `git switch` will do this *automatically* when appropriate.

That is, if you have an `origin/feature/tall` remote-tracking name, but *do not* yet have a `feature/tall` *branch* name, and you run `git checkout feature/tall`, rather than giving you an error message to the effect that `feature/tall` does not exist, `git checkout` will say to itself: *Hm, `feature/tall` does not exist, but `origin/feature/tall` does.  I'll bet my user wishes to create `feature/tall` such that it identifies the same commit as `origin/feature/tall`!*  So `git checkout` does that, and then, having created the branch name, `git checkout` can check out that new branch.

If this fails for some reason, you can always do it explicitly:

```
git checkout -b feature/tall origin/feature/tall
```

for instance.  (There are a lot of smaller items that branch names offer, that this glosses over, that are configurable through `git config`: automatic upstream setting, for instance.  The variant of `git checkout` that automatically creates a branch, obeys several settings.  Read through [the `git branch` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) and [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) to see what these are, but note that there are a *lot* of options and configuration knobs: it's easy to get lost in all these settings.)